# Exec bad access problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

```
#import "DealList.h"
#import "MyGroupOnDetailedViewController.h"
#import "Deal.h"
#import "DDXML.h"
@implementation DealList


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    xmlString = [self textToHtml:xmlString];    
    NSError *error = nil;
    DDXMLDocument *ddDoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    DDXMLElement *FeaturedDeal = [ddDoc rootElement];
    Deals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (DDXMLElement *n in [FeaturedDeal children]) {
        Deal *deal = [[Deal alloc]init];
        deal.DealID = [[[n elementsForName:@"DealId"]objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        deal.Available = [[[n elementsForName:@"Available"]objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",deal.Available);
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [Deals count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 120.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    //this works
    NSLog(@"%@",[[Deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Available]);
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyGroupOnDetailedViewController *myGroupOnDetailedViewController = [[MyGroupOnDetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyGroupOnDetailedViewController" bundle:nil];
    myGroupOnDetailedViewController.DealID = [[Deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] DealID];
//EXC_BAD_ACCESS:
myGroupOnDetailedViewController.available = [[Deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Available];
}
@end
```

`myGroupOnDetailedViewController.available = [[Deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Available];`
This line is getting bad access 
But while writing the same code in cellForRowAtIndexPath printing the value of Available, DealID can be accessed everywhere.

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1652.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""Settings.m":50" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - ""MyGroupOnDetailedViewController.m":103" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - ""DealList.m":184" resolved
Pending breakpoint 4 - ""DealList.m":166" resolved
Pending breakpoint 5 - ""MyGroupOnDetailedViewController.m":75" resolved
Pending breakpoint 6 - ""DealList.m":50" resolved
2011-06-28 14:21:18.139 Feature_list[1652:207] (null)
2011-06-28 14:21:18.151 Feature_list[1652:207] <FeaturedDeal><DealId>167</DealId><Text>$10 for $100 worth Indian fare</Text><ImageUrl>2011/06/large_167.jpg</ImageUrl><Hilights>999999999,88888888,8888888888,8888888888888888,788888,6666666666,555555555</Hilights><Fineprint>77777777777,666666666,555555555,444444444,333333333,2222222222,1111111111</Fineprint><Company>Taiba Foods</Company><ExpiryDate>2011-06-24 22:22:54</ExpiryDate><Value>100</Value><Discount>90</Discount><BuyerCount>1</BuyerCount></FeaturedDeal>
2011-06-28 14:21:18.152 Feature_list[1652:207] Deal ID is: (null)
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2011-06-28 14:21:23.694 Feature_list[1652:207] Error:(null)
2011-06-28 14:21:23.697 Feature_list[1652:207] 1
2011-06-28 14:21:23.697 Feature_list[1652:207] (null)
2011-06-28 14:21:23.698 Feature_list[1652:207] 1
2011-06-28 14:21:23.699 Feature_list[1652:207] (null)
2011-06-28 14:21:23.701 Feature_list[1652:207] deal 3
2011-06-28 14:21:23.703 Feature_list[1652:207] Expiry Date:2011-06-01 08:02:51 +0000
2011-06-28 14:21:23.704 Feature_list[1652:207] test
(gdb) continue
2011-06-28 14:21:24.117 Feature_list[1652:207] 1
2011-06-28 14:21:24.119 Feature_list[1652:207] $10 for $100 worth Indian fare
2011-06-28 14:21:24.120 Feature_list[1652:207] Expiry Date:2011-06-30 16:52:54 +0000
2011-06-28 14:21:24.121 Feature_list[1652:207] test
(gdb) continue
2011-06-28 14:21:25.333 Feature_list[1652:207] 1
2011-06-28 14:21:27.711 Feature_list[1652:207] <Deal: 0x4e86b40>
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please actually provide information about the problem you are having and what you have tried so far. Or at the very least, what the debugger says so we know which part of the code to look at.

Comment: On which line you get bad access.

Comment: Can you post your crash log too?

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: If you're running in a debugger, can you please press CMD + Shift + R while running the app to bring up the console, and paste its contents at the bottom of your question, after you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

Comment: Enter `backtrace` in the console and paste the output here.

Comment: #0  0x01050a67 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add NSZombieEnabled in your XCode project..

You can find out the error..

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Answer (score 2):

With what little information we have, are you sure it's not something silly like

```
myGroupOnDetailedViewController.available
```

should be

```
myGroupOnDetailedViewController.Available
```

I don't have access to the definition of this object, but you're using uppercase A everywhere else...

Comment: To add, it would be great if one adopts the [`coding conventions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) of the platform.

Comment: @interface Deal : NSObject {
 
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *DealID;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *Available;
@end


@interface MyGroupOnDetailedViewController : UIViewController {
 NSString *DealID;
 NSString *available;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *DealID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *available;
@end

Comment: Actually problem lies in RHS i.e., "[[Deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Available]" while NSLOging or assigning. LHS is ok.